# How can I remove the 0 from the chapter title of my ToC, which now appears as 'Contents 0'?

Tags: table-of-contents

I've adjusted the default chapter numbering to a large number on the right side of the page, but now the ToC also shows a chapter number. How can I remove this number without removing the numbers of the other chapters?

[image: Screenshot of the display]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % for éô
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % for proper word breaking at line ends
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
                                % for page size and margin settings
\usepackage{graphicx}           % for ?
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    % for better equations
\usepackage{amsthm}             % for better theorem styles
\usepackage{mathtools}          % for greek math symbol formatting
\usepackage{enumitem}           % for control of 'enumerate' numbering
\usepackage{listings}           % for control of 'itemize' spacing
\usepackage{todonotes}          % for clear TODO notes
\usepackage{hyperref}           % page numbers and '\ref's become clickable
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % for the chapter style
\usepackage{fix-cm}             % for the chapter style

%% TODO PACKAGE
\newcommand{\towrite}[2]{\todo[inline,color=yellow!10]{TO WRITE: #1}}

%************** Chapter style
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{#1}\hfill%
    \parbox[b]{2cm}{\hfill{\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont\thechapter}}%
  }
%**************


\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\input{Chapter1_Introduction.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter2_Theory.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter3_MethodMaterials.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter4_Results.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter5_Conclusion.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter6_Recommendations.tex}


\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just comment the line `\parbox[b]{2cm}{\hfill{\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont\thechapter}}%`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! With commenting that line the 0 is gone, but the numbering of the other chapters as well... I would like to keep the big number for the other chapters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. You can redefine the KOMA-Script macros `\chapterformat` and `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\LARGE}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
  \parbox[b]{2cm}{\hfill{\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont\thechapter}}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{\raggedchapter#3}\hfill#2}
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% other section levels with style=chapter
}
```

Example  (without the unrelated packages and code):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% a4paper is default
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % only needed with older TeX Distributionen
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % for proper word breaking at line ends
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fix-cm}             % 
\usepackage{hyperref}           % load as last package

%%************** Chapter style
\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\LARGE}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
  \parbox[b]{2cm}{\hfill{\fontsize{80}{96}\selectfont\thechapter}}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{\raggedchapter#3}\hfill#2}
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% other section levels with style=chapter
}
\makeatother

% pagestyle empty in toc:
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes it looks exactly how I want it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add this for unnumbered chapters in your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filright}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
```